# (Final)Simple Decryptor/Encryptor

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, cryptography, caesar-cipher

This is my final version of my simpel Decrypter/Encryptor called Dencryptor. This is one of my first Python projects and I think it turned out pretty good. I am using a Caesar cipher right now and I think it is working as intended. I may try to add some other ciphers to it but I think it is working good right now. This was just a project to learn from and the encryption isn't strong so I do not recommend any one actually using this for anything.

List of commands:

- help - Show this page.
- encrypt {text} - Encrypt some text
- key - Displays your current decryption key
- key {key} - Set a decryption key
- decrypt {text} - Decrypt some text
- exit - close application

What do you guys think about it? Any changes required?

Special thanks to: [@Coal_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/139640/coal) and [@henje](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/89233/henje) for helping!

```
    import secrets
    import string

    print("""  _____                                   _            
     |  __ \                                 | |           
     | |  | | ___ _ __   ___ _ __ _   _ _ __ | |_ ___ _ __ 
     | |  | |/ _ \ '_ \ / __| '__| | | | '_ \| __/ _ \ '__|
     | |__| |  __/ | | | (__| |  | |_| | |_) | ||  __/ |   
     |_____/ \___|_| |_|\___|_|   \__, | .__/ \__\___|_|   
                                   __/ | |                 
                                  |___/|_|                 """)
    userinput = ''
    exit = False
    key = None
    characters = list(string.printable)[:-5]


    def get_int(prompt):
            try:
                return int(prompt)
            except ValueError:
                print("Input requires a number!")


    def encrypt(args, key):
        text = []
        encryptlist = []
        try:
            for line in args:
                text.extend(line)
            for x in range(len(text)):
                index = characters.index(text[x])
                newindex = (index + key) % len(characters)
                cipher = characters[newindex]
                encryptlist.append(cipher)
                x += 1
            encrypted = ''.join(encryptlist)
            return encrypted
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid character(s)!')


    def decrypt(args, key):
        text = []
        decryptlist = []
        try:
            for line in args:
                text.extend(line)
            for x in range(len(text)):
                index = characters.index(text[x])
                newindex = (index - key) % len(characters)
                cipher = characters[newindex]
                decryptlist.append(cipher)
                x += 1
            decrypted = ''.join(decryptlist)
            return decrypted
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid character(s)!')


    while not exit:
        arguments = ''
        userinput = input('> ')
        command = userinput.split(' ', 1)[0]

        if userinput != command:
            arguments = userinput.split(' ', 1)[1]

        if userinput == 'help':
            print('''
    Dencrypter commands
    ------------------------------------------
    help - Show this page.
    encrypt {text} - Encrypt some text
    key - Displays your current decryption key
    key {key} - Set a decryption key
    decrypt {text} - Decrypt some text
    exit - close application
            ''')

        if userinput == 'exit':
            exit = True

        elif command == 'encrypt':
            encryptionkey = secrets.randbits(10)
            encryption = encrypt(arguments, encryptionkey)
            if arguments != '':
                if encryption is not None:
                    print('Encrypted tekst: ' + encryption)
                    print('Encryption key: ' + str(encryptionkey))
            else:
                print('The encrypt command requires an argument. \nUse like this: encrypt {text}')

        elif command == 'key':
            if arguments != '':
                key = get_int(arguments)
                if key is not None:
                    print('Decryption key changed to: ' + str(key))
            else:
                print('Decryption key: ' + str(key))

        elif command == 'decrypt':
            if arguments != '':
                print('Decrypted tekst: ' + decrypt(arguments, key))
                print('Using decryption key: ' + str(key))
            else:
                print('The decrypt command requires an argument. \nUse like this: decrypt {tekst}')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a nice program, intuitively usable and good if you don't have any cryptographically versed attacker.

When I tried it, my session looked like this:

```
> encrypt Hello
Encrypted text: (ELLO
Encryption key: 311
> decrypt (ELLO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rillig/git/python-playground/caesar.py", line 105, in <module>
    print('Decrypted tekst: ' + decrypt(arguments, key))
  File "C:/Users/rillig/git/python-playground/caesar.py", line 52, in decrypt
    newindex = (index - key) % len(characters)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Oops. But that's easy to fix.

Like in every Python review here, have a look at [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide. It has lots of tips on how to structure the code and format it nicely. Yes, it's a long document, so read it in little steps, as you have time.

In your greeting string, the first line looks weird. When you add a backslash immediately after the opening `"""`, the first line break is ignored in the string:

```
print("""\
  _____                                   _
 |  __ \                                 | |
 | |  | | ___ _ __   ___ _ __ _   _ _ __ | |_ ___ _ __
 | |  | |/ _ \ '_ \ / __| '__| | | | '_ \| __/ _ \ '__|
 | |__| |  __/ | | | (__| |  | |_| | |_) | ||  __/ |
 |_____/ \___|_| |_|\___|_|   \__, | .__/ \__\___|_|
                               __/ | |
                              |___/|_|                 """)
```

Now your logo looks good in the source code also.

To quote from your code:

```
characters = list(string.printable)[:-5]
```

Be careful that the encrypted text does not end in a space. That would not be visible on the screen. Imagine this small dialog:

> Q: How much do I owe you?
>   A: 150

Now if that is encrypted and the final 0 is missing, that would be bad.

Continuing with your code:

```
except ValueError:
    print('Invalid character(s)!')
```

This error message is a bit unspecific. If your program is friendly, it tells me which of the many characters I typed is invalid, ideally with some context so that I can find it.

```
        print('''
Dencrypter commands
------------------------------------------
help             Show this page
encrypt {text}   Encrypt some text
key              Display your current decryption key
key {key}        Set a decryption key
decrypt {text}   Decrypt some text
exit             Close application
        ''')
```

I reformatted this usage section to start all descriptions in the same column. That way, I can easily scan the first word of each description to see which of the verbs is most appropriate to what I want to do.

I also normalized the periods at the end, the upper/lower spelling of the first letter and replaced `Displays` with `Display`, to match the grammar of the other entries.

By the way, it's great that you use actual verbs as the commands. I see many other beginner programs that have numbered menu items: Press 1 to encrypt a text. Press 2 to enter a decryption key. And so on. Your variant is the way to go.

You should normalize `tekst` to `text`. :)

I really like the `Use it like this` instructions. They are essential for having fun with the program. "Don't tell me what I did wrong, rather tell me how to do it correctly."

To make your program easily testable, it should do all of its work in a function called `main`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163) for further details.